# Instantiate custom class returning null object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Creating a Conway's Game of Life game and I am trying to fill the screen with an initial set of random Cells.

I created the "Cell" Class and within this I have a simple method that takes in a bool to set the Cell as alive or not.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cell : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isAlive = false;
    public int numNeighbors = 0;

    public void SetAlive (bool alive)
    {
        isAlive = alive;

        if (alive)
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
        } else 
        {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When Instantiating the GameObject (a 16x16 black square) as a Cell, I get a Null Object:
[image: print on console of the cell]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    private static int SCREEN_WIDTH = 64;       // 1024 pixels
    private static int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 48;      // 768  pixels

    Cell[,] grid = new Cell[SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT];   //grid for cells
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PlaceCells();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        
    }

    void PlaceCells ()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; x++)
            {   
                Cell cell = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Cell"), new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity) as Cell;
                grid[x, y] = cell;
            }
        }

    }

    bool RandomAliveCell ()
    {
        int rand = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, 100);

        if (rand > 75)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


}
```

I´m new to C# and to Unity so please, if you can, provide a more detailed explanation or documentation so I could learn more :)

[image: Cell prefab Unity]

Comment: `Resources.Load` only works inside a `Resources` folder. Where the provided path is relative to any `Resources` folder. Is your cell prefab in the path `Resources\Prefabs\Cell.prefab`? [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

Comment: Hi Matt, yes it is :)

Comment: can you try using the typed version, so `Resources.Load<Cell>(..)`? Can you confirm the Cell script it attached to the prefab? Can you move the Resources.Load into a variable above instantiate and debug and see if it's actually finding a prefab?

Comment: I did the following:
`Cell prefabCell = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Cell") as Cell;`
`Cell cell = Instantiate(prefabCell, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity) as Cell;`

Still comes in as a Null object

Comment: `prefabCell` is that null, did you debug? Can you also try `object test = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Cell")` I mainly want to see if it's actually finding a prefab but the `as Cell` is nullifying it (because it's not got the Cell script) or it's not finding the prefab at all. Need to find where it's failing to be able to diagnose why it's failing

Comment: Using `Object prefabCell = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Cell");`  returns a UnityEngine.GameObject

Comment: Presume that means that it isn´t transforming the GameObject as Cell

Comment: Right now we've confirmed the prefab is being picked up I think you need this. `GameObject createdCellObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Cell"), new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity); Cell cell = createdCellObject.GetComponent<Cell>()`

Comment: I still get that cell is a Null
`GameObject prefabCell = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Cell"), new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;`
`Cell cell = prefabCell.GetComponent<Cell>();`

Comment: So I assume `prefabCell` is not null, otherwise, you'd get a nullref exception. This means `GetComponent<Cell>` hasn't worked and that means the prefab doesn't have a `Cell` script attached to it

Comment: I just checked and the prefab (in unity) has the Cell script attached to it. Forgive my ignorance, but I´m not sure how I can amend thata

Comment: What does the structure of the Cell prefab look like? Is it 1 object with the Cell script on, or is the Cell Script on a child object? Maybe edit your question with a screenshot of the prefab structure. Maybe you need `GetComponentInChildren` instead. Otherwise I think this is the extend of my knowledge without actually having the project to look at xD

Comment: Yeah my bad, thought of it and then got mixed up with something. Should be uploaded now

Comment: `GetComponentInChildren ` still returns `Null`